# Unix command understanding a sed script

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I need help in understanding the following code. Why are N and D used here? What do they mean here?

This is a `sed` command to print duplicated lines of input.

```
sort file | sed '$!N; s/^\(.*\)\n\1$/\1/; t; D'
```

Comment: Have you attempted to read the `sed` man page? `sed` manual? Online guides to `sed`? Any one of those could have explained to you what the `N` and `D` commands do. If you *have* read those and *still* don't understand then indicate that and give an explanation of whatever sense you *have* made (or at least tried to make) of the `sed` script.

Comment: You could look at the POSIX [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)
specification, or you can look at the manual for the variant of `sed` on your system.  The two do not necessarily match, though they will on the code shown.  The `N` and `D` operations are the easy ones in the script shown; it's the `s///` and `t` that are trickier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a translation of the script:

```
for each line of input:      # sed does this loop automatically

    if it's not the last line:     # This is what $! means

        append a \n (newline) to the current line           # N means this
        append the next line of input to the current line   # and this

    # Note that the "current line" may now contain a \n in the middle!

    if the current line matches some string, followed by a \n,
            followed by that same string again:               # s command's pattern
        delete the \n and the second copy of the string       # s command's action

    if the s command matched:       # t means this
        go to endOfScript           # and this

    delete everything up to the first \n in the current line  # D means this
    go to endOfLoop                                           # and this

  endOfScript:
    print the current line, followed by \n, to stdout    # sed does this automatically

  endOfLoop:
    # just return to the top of the loop for the next line of input
```

The D command is actually a little more complicated: it suppresses the reading of the next line at the top of the loop, if the current line has any characters left. But that's never the case in this sed script.

Answer (score 1):

According to [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed),

> `N`  is specifying Read/append the next line of input into the pattern
>   space.
>
> `D`    Delete up to the first embedded newline in the pattern space.
>   Start next cycle, but skip reading from the input if there is still
>   data in the pattern space.
>
> `$`    Match the last line.
>
> `!`  Signifies it doesn't match actual definition of `N`
>
> `t label`  If a `s///` has done a successful substitution since the
>   last input line was read and since the last `t` or `T` command, then
>   branch to label; if label is omitted, branch to end of script.